# How to keep discord bot on replit alive

Tags: python, discord, replit

I'm very new to replit and python.
I'm using this [Github Project](https://github.com/Zero6992/chatGPT-discord-bot) to host my own discord bot on replit.

The project is working fine but I just cannot get to stay alive, the moment I close
my replit project, then the bot goes offline.

How can I fix this?

I'm using this code to try and keep it alive but it is not working.

keep_alive.py

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')


@app.route('/')
def home():
  return "I'm alive"


def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)


def keep_alive():
  t = Thread(target=run)
  t.start()
```

main.py

```
from src import keep_alive
from src import bot
import sys


def check_verion() -> None:
  import pkg_resources
  import src.log

  # init loggger
  logger = src.log.setup_logger(__name__)

  # Read the requirements.txt file and add each line to a list
  with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

  # For each library listed in requirements.txt, check if the corresponding version is installed
  for package in required:
    # Use the pkg_resources library to get information about the installed version of the library
    package_name, package_verion = package.split('==')
    installed = pkg_resources.get_distribution(package_name)
    # Extract the library name and version number
    name, version = installed.project_name, installed.version
    # Compare the version number to see if it matches the one in requirements.txt
    if package != f'{name}=={version}':
      logger.error(
        f'{name} version {version} is installed but does not match the requirements'
      )
      sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  check_verion()
  bot.run_discord_bot()
  keep_alive()
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You should host a flask app on a real server.

Comment: What do you mean, a flask app on a real server?

Comment: Can I host this on C-Panel ?

Comment: Yes, you can host it on the server managed in C-Panel.

Comment: `keep_alive.py` is the code that starts a flask app. This is what I am referring to. I've never written a discord bot, but I think this is actually unecessary.

Comment: I need to back up a little here. I recommend that you first learn how to run the bot on your own computer. This might be the easiest solution.

Comment: The code in `keep_alive.py` I found in some tutorial on the net, I myself don't know much about flask app.

Comment: The code is working just fine on my computer, I have no issue running the app, I just need to figure out how to keep it live 24/7

Comment: You should delete `keep_alive.py`. It has nothing to do with a discord bot.

Comment: I have a shared hosting server with C-Panel, but there is no option to install a python app anywhere

Comment: One option is to just run the bot on your computer. As long as you never turn off your computer, the bot will run 24/7. Otherwise, you will need to learn how to host your code on a server, such as the one you manage in c-panel.

Comment: So looking at the code `bot.run_discord_bot()` has the line `client.run(TOKEN)`. This function will run the bot but prevent the line after ` keep_alive()` from being called. Since the keep alive function is not being executed the webserver is never actually online and is why the bot doesnt stay alive.

Comment: Also once you get the address of the flask app you'll need to use some monitoring service like uptime robot or better uptime to ping the flask webserver like every 30min.

Comment: Btw i wouldn't recommend using replit to host a discord bot because of its shared hosting and its really unreliable. Instead i think you should either run it on a vps or on your own computer

Comment: oracle has a great free teir incase you need a free vps to host the bot on (https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/).

Comment: Also from your comments it seems that you dont understand why the reason for the keep_alive file. Basically replit wont run after you close it but if you host a website it will stay up until theres like an hour of inactivity (thats why the ping tool).

Comment: - The machines are super underpowered.
- - This means your bot will lag a lot as it gets bigger.
- You'll need a web server alongside your bot to prevent it from being shut off. 
- - This isn't a trivial task, and eats more of the machines power.
- Repl.it uses an ephemeral file system.
- - This means any file you saved via your bot will be overwritten when you next launch.
- They use a shared IP for everything running on the service.
This one is important - if someone is running a user bot on their service and gets banned, everyone on that IP will be banned. Including you.

Comment: The above comment is reasons why not to use replit ^

Comment: See [more info about Replit being rate limited](https://ask.replit.com/t/discord-ratelimit/3522?u=not-ethan)